# Can't use tag explaining which version I have

Tags: discussion, tags, version-tags

I'm sorry, but it's totally STUPID that you can't use something like 10.8 or execute as a tag... it's the version of my mac and it's an important piece of information. I shouldn't need a reputation of 1500 to tell people which version I have. that is DUMB!

thanks.

Comment: There are over 1000 questions tagged as [tag:osx-mountain-lion]. This was chosen because the tag name [tag:10.8] wouldn't have meaning on its own, and the community has decided to prefer the names instead of the version numbers for OS X because they're more frequently used.

Comment: Please compose your complaint in some way other than an ejaculation of disparagement, with something that at least resembles an argument for your point of view, and maybe even a proposal for change. As it stands, this is just a waste of our time.

Answer (score 16):

Neither [10.8](/questions/tagged/10.8) or [execute](/questions/tagged/execute) work very well as standalone tags.  They're both too vague.

You **can** add the tag [osx-mountain-lion](/questions/tagged/osx-mountain-lion) which is meant to convey exactly the sort of version information you're looking to add.

There's no good solution for [execute](/questions/tagged/execute), because it's just too vague to be useful.

Comment: Hng. Almost 600 questions tagged `execute`.

Answer (score 13):

You *should* put this kind of information in your question (text). If you must, you could put it in the title as well...

If you *really* must, you could open a request (here on meta) to add the tag, I suppose. (But I do not think it will be honored.)

The 1500 reputation requirement is to prevent lots of unnecessary/incorrect tag creations. Which seems to be working nicely in this situation..!